# Directly read SMS when it arrives via GSM modem in PC over Serial Communication

Tags: gsm, at-command

I am using SIM9000A GSM Modem and have it connected it to my PC.

The issue is that whenever SMS is received by my SIM I receive below data in PC:

**+CMTI: "SM",8**

I want that all incoming SMS should be directly be read in PC and need not send any further command. Something like when SMS comes - GSM modem should actually send SMS content to serial port.

Below is the output received for CPMS enq.

**AT+CPMS=?**

**+CPMS: ("SM"),("SM"),("SM")**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AT+CNMI command to tell the GSM modem to direct incoming messages directly to the serial port. The full command, with parameters, is: **AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0**

**AT+CNMI=2,1,0,0,0** sets the modem back to *indication only* mode and **AT+CNMI=2,0,0,0,0** does not send any indication when a new message is received.